# Stuck on porting OpenGL API loader implemented by 64-bit masm to that implemented by 32-bit

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, opengl, masm

I am recently porting a OpenGL API loader implemented by 64-bit masm to that of 32-bit, part of 64-bit [source codes](https://github.com/google/filament/blob/main/libs/bluegl/src/BlueGLCoreWindowsImpl.S) are as follows:

```
.code

extrn __blue_glCore_glMultiDrawArraysIndirectBindlessCountNV: qword
glMultiDrawArraysIndirectBindlessCountNV proc
    mov r11, __blue_glCore_glMultiDrawArraysIndirectBindlessCountNV
    jmp r11
glMultiDrawArraysIndirectBindlessCountNV endp

extrn __blue_glCore_glCopyTexImage1D: qword
glCopyTexImage1D proc
    mov r11, __blue_glCore_glCopyTexImage1D
    jmp r11
glCopyTexImage1D endp
...
```

e.g. external symbol `__blue_glCore_glMultiDrawArraysIndirectBindlessCountNV` will be load when calling `glMultiDrawArraysIndirectBindlessCountNV`. My 32-bit modifications(change all `qword` to `dword`, all `r11` to `eax`) are:

```
.model flat
.code

extrn __blue_glCore_glMultiDrawArraysIndirectBindlessCountNV: dword
glMultiDrawArraysIndirectBindlessCountNV proc
    mov eax, __blue_glCore_glMultiDrawArraysIndirectBindlessCountNV
    jmp eax
glMultiDrawArraysIndirectBindlessCountNV endp

extrn __blue_glCore_glCopyTexImage1D: dword
glCopyTexImage1D proc
    mov eax, __blue_glCore_glCopyTexImage1D
    jmp eax
glCopyTexImage1D endp
```

When other targets link this loader during compilation, the compiler(I used Visual Studio 2019) complains **unresolved external symbol** error. I actually know little about MASM, who can help me out?

**Update1**
I have created a mini demo in this [repo](https://github.com/FinleyPan/bluegl/tree/master) to reproduce this problem, which can be built directly with Visual Studio and cmake. In particular, these [lines](https://github.com/FinleyPan/bluegl/blob/master/tests/test_bluegl.cpp#L36-L39) puzzle me:

```cpp
GLint major = 0, minor = 0;
//these two symbol are found
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &major);
glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &minor);
//this symbol is missed
glActiveTexture(0);
```

why only symbols of opengl1.0 and 1.1(opengl32.lib) loaded while others missed?

**Update2**
My Visual Studio linker complains:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  test_bluegl E:\CPPCode\projects\bluegl\build\Debug\test_bluegl.exe  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _glActiveTexture@4 referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall bluegl::BlueGLTest_GetVersion_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@BlueGLTest_GetVersion_Test@bluegl@@EAEXXZ)    test_bluegl E:\CPPCode\projects\bluegl\build\test_bluegl.obj    1
```

then I use `dumpbin.exe` to check generated symbol in `bluegl.lib`:

```
...
55DF0 _glActiveTexture@0
...
```

So I changed the corresponding proc to:

```
extrn __blue_glCore_glActiveTexture: dword
glActiveTexture proc param : dword
    mov edx, __blue_glCore_glActiveTexture
    jmp edx
glActiveTexture endp
```

Now the generated symbol was right and linking is OK, but new problems arose:

1. Visual Studio will report:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   LNK2026 module unsafe for SAFESEH image.    test_bluegl E:\CPPCode\projects\bluegl\build\bluegl.lib(BlueGLCoreWindowsImpl.obj)  1   
    Error   LNK1281 Unable to generate SAFESEH image.   test_bluegl E:\CPPCode\projects\bluegl\build\Debug\test_bluegl.exe  1
```

without setting `/safeseh` property for the masm source.
2 It's too heavy to append parameter list for each api, and I don't know why 64-bit masm not requiring parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

Select a C implementation as workaround, but still interested in a masm32 implementation.